# how to find an elements under same parents

Tags: jquery, parent, siblings

I'm trying to make a hover on `.detail` cause the img in `.imgbox_wrapper` to be magnified.

I tried to use closest or siblings but couldn't find how to select an element which is located in a parents sibling.

```
<div class="imgbox">
     <div class="sec03_text">
          <p class="design">Exterior</p>
          <button class="detail">
              <p>text</p>
          </button>
     </div>
     <div class="imgbox_wrapper">
          <img src="image/exterior.png" alt="nth">
     </div>
</div>
```

here is what I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sec03_text .detail').hover(function() {
        $('.imgbox .imgbox_wrapper img').css('transform : scale(1.1)');
    });

});
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the javascript/jQuery code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on the main parent once you find it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.detail').hover(function(){
    //this runs on mouse enter
    $(this).closest('.imgbox').find('.imgbox_wrapper img').css('transform','scale(2,2)');
  }, function(){
    //this runs on mouse leave
    $(this).closest('.imgbox').find('.imgbox_wrapper img').css('transform','scale(1,1)');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgbox">
     <div class="sec03_text">
          <p class="design">Exterior</p>
          <button class="detail">
              <p>text</p>
          </button>
     </div>
     <div class="imgbox_wrapper">
          <img src="image/exterior.png" alt="nth">
     </div>
</div>
```